# What is the main difference between the systemc constructor and normal C++ constructor? Can we declare the systemc constructor in private?

Tags: systemc

While working in the system c program I missed out the public keyword before constructor, but the program works fine.
But in C++, its throwing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemC requires that first parameter to module constructor should be `sc_module_name`. Other than that, there is nothing special. SystemC macros `SC_MODULE` and `SC_CTOR` just save you some time, but you are not required to use them.

```
SC_MODULE( dut ) {
    SC_CTOR(dut) { }
};
```

Is equivalent to:

```
struct dut : sc_core::sc_module {
    typedef dut SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE;
    dut(::sc_core::sc_module_name) {}
};
```

Please note that `struct` members are public by-default, and `class` members are private by default. If you use `class` instead of `struct`, you will need to make them public by adding `public:` explicitly:

```
class dut : public sc_core::sc_module {
    typedef dut SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE;

public:
    dut(::sc_core::sc_module_name) {}
};
```